# How to save an IPython Notebook as PDF?

Tags: pdf, ipython

So, as the title say, i'm  having a little trouble saving my notebooks as PDF, 
when i try:

```
ipython nbconvert --to latex --post PDF MyNotebook.ipynb
```

i get the error:

```
File "<ipython-input-4-329ffed1c22e>", line 1
ipython nbconvert --to latex --post PDF Presentacion.ipynb
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

and i have no idea how to solve this, plus i also want to save it as a slide, but i get same error, does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Try running `ipython nbconvert --to latex --post PDF Presentacion.ipynb` from command line. You cannot use this command in the interpreter.

Comment: Still doesn't work, i get:    C:\Anaconda>"ipython" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: This means that `ipython` is not in your `PATH` variable, therefore it cannot be found. There could be multiple reasons for that. Unfortunately, I don't have a windows to test.

Comment: I fix that, so i dont get that error anymore, insted when i try the nbconvert command i get this message: ` nknl`

Comment: Please refer to:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29156653/ipython-jupyter-problems-saving-notebook-as-pdf

Comment: Please refer to:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29156653/ipython-jupyter-problems-saving-notebook-as-pdf I hope it helps.
Behrouz

Answer (score 5):

On PC, in Jupyter, you can choose 'File > print preview' instead of converting or 'Download as' it. Then you can right lick on the print preview and choose print. From here, you can choose to 'Save as PDF'.
Here is the process:

[image: Print Preview]

[image: Print]

[image: Save as PDF]

I hope it helps.

Behrouz

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [sagemath](https://cloud.sagemath.com) cloud version, you can simply go to the left corner, 

select File --> Download as --> Pdf via LaTeX (.pdf)

Check the screenshot if you want.

[Screenshot Convert ipynb to pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHEKF.png)

If it dosn't work for any reason, you can try another way. 

select File --> Print Preview and then on the preview 

right click --> Print and then select save as pdf.