# IPython/Jupyter Problems saving notebook as PDF

Tags: pdf, ipython, jupyter

So, I've been trying to save a jupyter notebook as PDF but I just can't figure out how to do this. The first thing I try is from the file menu just download as PDF, but doing that results in:

```
nbconvert failed: PDF creating failed
```

the next thing I try is try to do the conversion from the Command Prompt like this

```
$ ipython nbconvert --to latex --post PDF MyNotebook.ipynb
```

but again, this results in an error message

```
ImportError: No module named 'PDF'
```

and if I try

```
$ ipython nbconvert --to latex MyNotebook.ipynb
```

this results in

```
IPython.nbconvert.utils.pandoc.PandocMissing: Pandoc wasn't found:
Please check that pandoc is installed
```

if I try to install pandoc (`pip install pandoc`), this gives me

```
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
```

and this is where I get stuck because I just don't know what else to do.
Anyone have idea how to fix whatever is wrong?

Comment: creating pdf's requires non-pythonic dependencies (i.e `pandoc` and `latex`)

Comment: That means you have to install them before you can use this feature. And they're not python packages, therefore you cannot use pip.

Comment: [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) is written in Haskell.

Answer (score 61):

To make it work, I installed latex, typical latex extra, and pandoc.

With ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive texlive-latex-extra pandoc
```

it takes some times: several 100 Mb to download. I read somewhere that you can use `--no-install-recommends` for texlive and extra to reduce to the dl.

Comment: Mine required `pandoc` and `texlive-xetex`.

Comment: I found a smaller list of packages on [ask_ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/909811/743264).

Comment: I also needed `texlive-generic-extra` for solving [this issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392577/how-to-fix-iftex-sty-not-found-issue), apart from `texlive-xetex` that @douggard suggested.

Comment: Thanks a lot that was a great help :)

Comment: you are my hero!

Answer (score 44):

If you are on a Mac and have Homebrew installed, open a terminal shell and install pandoc typing the command:
**brew install pandoc**

be patient, time to install and compile can take a while on slow internet connections or older systems.

Comment: This worked on OS X 10.10. I can now convert to LaTeX and PDF.
(My installation on pandoc took less than a minute ... I must have had most of the components already on my system.)
THANKS!

Comment: @drpetermolnar This also worked for me (OSX 10.11.6). Took 2 minutes.

Comment: @Akshay, command is: ipython nbconvert --to PDF <your notebook>.ipynb

Comment: @AndreaNalon The command mentioned above isn't working, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43247818/error-in-converting-ipython-notebook-file-to-pdf

Comment: For OSX 10.13.06 I had to do:
``brew install pandoc`` and ``brew cask install mactex-no-gui`` .

Answer (score 21):

To convert notebooks to PDF you first need to have nbconvert installed.

```
pip install nbconvert
# OR
conda install nbconvert
```

Next, if you aren't using Anaconda or haven't already, you must install pandoc either by following the instructions on [their website](http://pandoc.org/installing.html) or, on Linux, as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install pandoc
```

After that you need to have XeTex installed on your machine:

- Linux : [TeX Live](http://tug.org/texlive/)
- Mac : [MacTex](http://tug.org/mactex/)
- Windows : [MikTex](http://miktex.org/)

You can now navigate to the folder that holds your IPython Notebook and run the following command:

```
jupyter nbconvert --to pdf MyNotebook.ipynb
```

for further reference, please check out [this link](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#installing-nbconvert).

Answer (score 13):

2015-4-22: It looks like an IPython update means that `--to pdf` should be used instead of `--to latex --post PDF`. There is a related [Github issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/7973).

Answer (score 11):

For converting any Jupyter notebook to PDF, please follow the below instructions:

(**Be inside Jupyter notebook**):

On **Mac OS**:

command + P --> you will get a print dialog box --> change destination as PDF --> Click print

On **Windows**:

Ctrl + P --> you will get a print dialog box --> change destination as PDF --> Click print

If the above steps doesn't generate **full PDF of the Jupyter notebook** (probably because Chrome, some times, don't print all the outputs because Jupyter make a scroll for big outputs),

**Try performing below steps for removing the auto scroll in the menu**:-

Credits: @ÂngeloPolotto

1. In your Jupyter Notebook, click **Cell** on top of the jupyter notebook
   [image]
2. Next click **All output** --> **Toggle scrolling** for removing auto scroll.

[image]

Comment: I agree, but Chrome, some times, don't print all the outputs because Jupyter make a scroll for big outputs. You need remove the auto scroll in the menu Cell->All Outputs->Toggle Scrolling (reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52803744/6846888)

Comment: Can you add this information in your answer? This can be very helpful for more users.

Comment: Yes @ÂngeloPolotto,I have added your information in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

As the comments to the question say, you will need pandoc and latex (e.g. TeXShop).  I installed pandoc with Homebrew, it took just a second.  Having pandoc and TeXShop, I could generate latex but not pdf (on the command line).

```
ipython nbconvert --to latex mynotebook.ipynb
```

Exploring the latex (.tex) file with TeXShop, the failure was due to missing stylesheets and defs.  After installing all of these (adjustbox.sty, adjcalc.sty, trimclip.sty, collectbox.sty, tc-pgf.def, ucs.sty, uni-global.def, utf8x.def, ucsencs.def), it did finally work.

However, the result looks a little too funky for my taste.  It is too bad that printing the html from Safari loses the syntax coloring.  Otherwise, it doesn't look so bad.  (This is all on OS X).

Comment: The following short line directly generated a PDF file without leaving any intermediary files created through compilation. `jupyter nbconvert --to pdf filename.ipynb
`

Comment: At least they have a fix for printing with color now so that printing the HTML directly to PDF is less bad: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/840

Answer (score 5):

I am using Anaconda-Jupyter Notebook on OS: Ubuntu 16.0 for Python programming.

#### Install Nbconvert, Pandoc, and Tex:

Open a terminal and implement the following commands in it.

#### Install Nbconvert: though it's part of the Jupyter ecosystem still install it once again

```
$conda install nbconvert
```

Or

```
$pip install nbconvert
```

But I will recommend using conda instead pip if you are using anaconda

#### Install Pandoc: since Nbconvert uses Pandoc for converting markdown to formats other than HTML. Type following command

```
$sudo apt-get install pandoc
```

#### Install TeX: For converting to PDF, nbconvert uses the TeX. Type following command

```
$sudo apt-get install texlive-xetex
```

After execution of these commands, close the opened notebooks refresh the home page Or restart the kernel of the opened notebook. Now try to download notebook as a pdf :)

Note: For more details, please refer the official documentation:
https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

Answer (score 4):

This Python script has GUI to select with explorer a Ipython Notebook you want to convert to pdf. The approach with wkhtmltopdf is the only approach I found works well and provides high quality pdfs. Other approaches described here are problematic, syntax highlighting does not work or graphs are messed up.

You'll need to install wkhtmltopdf: 
http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html

and 
Nbconvert

```
pip install nbconvert
# OR
conda install nbconvert
```

**Python script**

```
# Script adapted from CloudCray
# Original Source: https://gist.github.com/CloudCray/994dd361dece0463f64a
# 2016--06-29
# This will create both an HTML and a PDF file

import subprocess
import os
from Tkinter import Tk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

WKHTMLTOPDF_PATH = "C:/Program Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf"  # or wherever you keep it

def export_to_html(filename):
    cmd = 'ipython nbconvert --to html "{0}"'
    subprocess.call(cmd.format(filename), shell=True)
    return filename.replace(".ipynb", ".html")


def convert_to_pdf(filename):
    cmd = '"{0}" "{1}" "{2}"'.format(WKHTMLTOPDF_PATH, filename, filename.replace(".html", ".pdf"))
    subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
    return filename.replace(".html", ".pdf")


def export_to_pdf(filename):
    fn = export_to_html(filename)
    return convert_to_pdf(fn)

def main():
    print("Export IPython notebook to PDF")
    print("    Please select a notebook:")

    Tk().withdraw() # Starts in folder from which it is started, keep the root window from appearing 
    x = askopenfilename() # show an "Open" dialog box and return the path to the selected file
    x = str(x.split("/")[-1])

    print(x)

    if not x:
        print("No notebook selected.")
        return 0
    else:
        fn = export_to_pdf(x)
        print("File exported as:\n\t{0}".format(fn))
        return 1

main()
```

Comment: script is kind of long for a stackoverflow reply really, and just wraps wkhtml.  I htink the answer will be clearer if you just put the commandline options for wkhtml, and an example.

Comment: so basically, you are using `nbconvert` to export to html, then using `wkhtmltopdf` to convert to pdf.  but this is not clear from your answer :-)

Comment: So, I tried this.  It is effectively better than exporting directly to pdf.  Weirdly, some of my mathjax is rendered correctly (at the start of the document), and then it stops rendering, about 12 pages into the document, for no obvious reason.

Answer (score 2):

notebook-as-pdfInstall
python -m pip install notebook-as-pdf pyppeteer-install

Use it
You can also use it with nbconvert:

jupyter-nbconvert --to PDFviaHTML filename.ipynb

which will create a file called filename.pdf.

or pip install notebook-as-pdf

create pdf from notebook jupyter-nbconvert-toPDFviaHTML

Comment: This solution failed to include images when I did it.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was experienced with both Ubuntu and Mac OSX. After a frantic set of searches and trials, both of them were solved. This requires both `tex` and `pandoc`; both jumbo external programs cannot installed by Python's `pip`.

> Mac OSX: using MacPorts installation of pandoc
>
> `port install pandoc`

This should take nearly an hour to complete (in the *usual* case). If the problem persists, you might have to install MacTeX distro. of TeXLive.

> For Ubuntu: install vanilla TeXLive from the [network installer](http://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html) -- **not through apt-get**. Then install pandoc using apt-get.
>
> `sudo apt-get install pandoc`

A complete installation of TeXLive would require a upto to 4.4 GB on disk.

To save all this trouble, the recommeded way to use IPython/Jupyter Notebook would be to install Anaconda Python distribution.

Answer (score 1):

I had all kinds of problems figuring this out as well. I don't know if it will provide exactly what you need, but I downloaded my notebook as an HTML file, then pulled it up in my Chrome browser, and then printed it as a PDF file, which I saved. It captured all my code, text and graphs. It was good enough for what I needed.

Comment: In my case, the html put one cell per page even if it is too long. So not a solution

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [sagemath](https://cloud.sagemath.com) cloud version, you can simply go to the left corner, 

select File --> Download as --> Pdf via LaTeX (.pdf)

Check the screenshot if you want.

[Screenshot Convert ipynb to pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghkg8.png)

If it dosn't work for any reason, you can try another way. 

select File --> Print Preview and then on the preview 

right click --> Print and then select save as pdf.

Comment: And if that doesn't work, you can directly use nbconvert on the command line and see exactly what is causing latex trouble.

Answer (score 1):

As a brand new member, I was unable to simply add a comment on the post but I want to second that the solution offered by Phillip Schwartz worked for me. Hopefully people in a similar situation will try that path sooner with the emphasis. Not having page breaks was a frustrating problem for quite a while so I am grateful for the discussion above.

As Phillip Schwartz said:
"You'll need to install wkhtmltopdf: [http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html][1]

and Nbconvert "

You then add a cell of the type "rawNBConvert" and include:

`<p style="page-break-after:always;"></p>`

That seemed to do the trick for me, and the generated PDF had the page break at the corresponding locations.
You don't need to run the custom code though, as it seems the "normal" path of downloading the notebook as HTML, opening in browser, and printing to PDF works once those utilities are installed.

Answer (score 1):

To convert .ipynb into pdf, your system should contain 2 components,

1. **nbconvert**:
   Is part of jupyter allows to convert ipynb to pdf

   > ```
   > pip install nbconvert
   > OR 
   > conda install nbconvert
   > ```
2. **XeTeX:**
   Convert ipynb to .tex format and then converting to pdf.

   > ```
   > sudo apt-get install texlive-xetex
   > ```

Then you can use below command to convert to pdf,

> ```
> ipython nbconvert --to pdf YOURNOTEBOOK.ipynb
> ```

In case, it doesn't work, install pandoc and try again.

> ```
> sudo apt-get install pandoc
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I had problems correctly displaying some symbols with regular *download as pdf*. So downloaded as tex `jupyter nbconvert --to latex "my notebook.ipynb"`, made some tweaks with notepad (as an example, in my case I needed these lines for my language

```
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage[lithuanian,english]{babel}
```

) and then exported to pdf with `latex --output-format=pdf "my notebook.tex"`.

But finally, however, to retain the same characters as you see in a browser I ended up using my Chrome browser printing: `Ctrl+P` `Print to pdf`. It adds unnecessary header and footer but everything else remains as it is. No more errors processing tqdm progress bar, no more code going out of the page and so on. Simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

In any system, the basic steps to correctly setup nbconvert  to convert ipython notebooks to pdf/latex are

1. Install nbconvert
2. Install pandoc
3. Install Texlive

**Installing nbconvert**

`pip install nbconvert`

or `conda install nbconvert`

**Installing pandoc**

`sudo apt-get install pandoc` for Ubuntu

or `sudo yum install pandoc` for CentOS

for others visit [pandoc-installation](https://pandoc.org/installing.html)

**Installing texlive**

You can install recommended packages or full install. For Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install texlive texlive-xetex texlive-generic-extra texlive-generic-recommended
```

`

For others and to full install texlive  follow the instructions given at  [tug](https://tug.org/texlive/) as per your system and choice.

I downloaded tar.gz file from  [tug-texlive-download](https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html) and followed instructions given at  [TeX Live - Quick install](https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html). Installation instructions in  summary:

1. Clean up

   `rm -rf /usr/local/texlive/2019`

   `rm -rf ~/.texlive2019`
2. Run installer

   unpack the zip file

   `cd /your/unpacked/directory`

   `perl install-tl`

   Enter command: i
3. Setting path

   `sudo vi /etc/bash.bashrc` and insert

   `PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH; export PATH`

   `MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/doc/man:$MANPATH; export MANPATH`

   `INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/doc/info:$INFOPATH; export INFOPATH`
4. Setting default papersize

   `tlmgr paper letter`

The commands may differ as per your system but the basic steps remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error in Windows 10. I followed these three steps and it solved my problem:

1. Install nbconvert

   pip install nbconvert
2. Install pandoc

https://pandoc.org/installing.html

3. Install miktex

https://miktex.org/download

---

Also it is good to update libraries:

```
pip install jupyter --upgrade
pip install --upgrade --user nbconvert
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on mac:

brew install texlive

Answer (score 0):

What I found was that the nbconvert/utils/pandoc.py had a code bug that resulted in the error for my machine. The code checks if pandoc is in your environmental variables path. For my machine the answer is no. However pandoc.exe is!

Solution was to add '.exe' to the code on line 69

```
if __version is None:
    if not which('pandoc.exe'):
        raise PandocMissing()
```

The same goes for 'xelatex' is not installed.
Add to the file nbconvert/exporters/pdf.py on line 94

```
    cmd = which(command_list[0]+'.exe')
```

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu users, an answer can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1177097/380799). I also quote it:

> The most probable cause, is that you have not installed the
>   appropriate dependencies. Your Ubuntu system has to have some packages
>   installed regarding conversion of LaTeX and XeTeX files, in order to
>   save your notebook as PDF. You can install them by:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install texlive texlive-xetex texlive-generic-extra texlive-generic-recommended pandoc
> ```
>
> Also, `nbconvert` is another dependency that is usually automatically
>   installed with jupyter. But you can install it just to be sure, while
>   having your virtual environment activated:
>
> ```
> pip install -U nbconvert
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You may go for below simple trick (works totally well with all **modern browsers**; on all recent operating systems - Windows, Mac, Linux) :

- Right click anywhere on your ipynb notebook.
- Select `Print...` . This will take you to the "Print-Preview Wizard" that will show you a PDF form of your python notebook.
- Provide the destination folder name. Click save.

Voila!!

This simple hack shall ofcourse save much of your time of installing nbviewer or miktex, pandoc or LaTex, etc. converter packages. Moreover, actually this hack works in same way, like you try to save an html webpage into PDF format.

Comment: ++ also, if you may want to or need be, allow or disallow `Toggle Scrolling` option in your ipynb notebook. Refer -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36757301/disable-ipython-notebook-autoscrolling