# Disable iPython Notebook Autoscrolling

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython

In iPython Notebook, is it possible to disable the autoscrolling of long outputs? Or at least set a threshold for the output length before autoscrolling sets in?

Tried the following command

```
%%javascript
IPython.OutputArea.auto_scroll_threshold = 9999;
```

but it gives an error

```
Javascript error adding output!
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
See your browser Javascript console for more details.
```

Comment: You may be able to edit the config file... In the meantime, if you click on the side of the result bar, it will rotate from `autoscroll` to `expanded` to `hidden`.

Answer (score 105):

Can also be done via user interface.

- Individual cells: **Cell->Current Outputs->Toggle Scrolling**
- All cells: **Cell->All Outputs->Toggle Scrolling**

[image]

Comment: The problem with this answer is that you have to do this every time you execute, it is not permanent

Comment: This does not work for JupyterLab because there is no Current Outputs menu.

Answer (score 85):

To disable auto-scrolling, execute this javascript in a notebook cell before other cells are executed:

```
%%javascript
IPython.OutputArea.prototype._should_scroll = function(lines) {
    return false;
}
```

There is also an ipython notebook extension, [disable_autoscroll](https://github.com/minrk/ipython_extensions/blob/master/extensions/disable_autoscroll.py), you can use for a more permanent change. Follow [ipython issue #2172](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/2172) for the latest details.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, when I run this, I get the same error as OP.

Comment: @frmsaul what version of IPython notebook are you using?  Still works for me in jupyter notebook 5.x (and 4.x).

Comment: Great, still works with current nbclassic notebook!

Answer (score 10):

To prevent scrolling within a single cell output, select the cell and press `Shift+O` while in command state. It will toggle output for that particular cell. If you want all the cells to display long outputs without scrolling, then go to the `Cell tab -> All Outputs -> Toggle Scrolling`. That's it !!!

Comment: This should be the answer to this ask.

Comment: You have to do this each time you run a notebook. The OP is asking about making it permanent.

Answer (score 6):

This works for me (with no semicolon)

```
    %%javascript
    IPython.OutputArea.auto_scroll_threshold = 9999
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: When I remove the semicolon at the end (after 9999) I don't get the error anymore

Answer (score 3):

To disable scroll to bottom after `run all` command, execute this code:

```
%%javascript
require("notebook/js/notebook").Notebook.prototype.scroll_to_bottom = function () {}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the similar way that you can [hack a cell to autorun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38856870/7290888), you can add the following cell:

```
%%javascript
require(
        ["notebook/js/outputarea"],
        function (oa) {
            oa.OutputArea.auto_scroll_threshold = -1;
            console.log("Setting auto_scroll_threshold to -1");
        });
```

which will set the `auto_scroll_threshold` to `-1` which means never autoscroll.

This works on my notebooks that are trusted (e.g. `jupyter trust notebook.ipynb`), not sure if *any* cells are executed in untrusted notebooks.

Answer (score 0):

For version 7 or higher, go to **Setting** > **Settings Editor** > **Jupyter Notebook Notebook** and uncheck **Auto Scroll Outputs**.

Note, the menu item **Settings Editor** is not available in the notebook view, only in the file browser.

Answer (score -1):

It can be done via UI. In the latest version (notebook 7) right clicking on the work area brings up the menu:
[image: Screenshot of the menu]

Comment: This will disable it at one time, but as soon as a new line of output is printed for the cell (e.g. if a loop is being executed), it will go back to scrolling!  so frustrating.