# python notebook cell height with matlibplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook

with this code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
%matplotlib notebook
x=np.arange(1,50)
y=np.arange(1,50)
X, Y =  np.meshgrid(x, y) 
Z = X*Y 
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1,
            cmap='viridis', edgecolor='none')
```

I get the below result, the figure does not fit into the cell area. I need to scroll up and down. This happens in my macbook, it does not happen in my linux machine.
any help will be appreciated. 
thanks

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I could not upload the image, I don't know why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you click on the grey area left of the cell output, it will unfold the output and show you the whole figure.

To change the settings permanently, check the following question:
[Disable iPython Notebook Autoscrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36757301/disable-ipython-notebook-autoscrolling)