# Running a Jupyter notebook from another notebook with parameters

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I want to run a full Jupyter notebook in a cycle, passing different parameters for each run of the notebook. I can pass parameters with addons as explained here:  [Passing command line arguments to argv in jupyter/ipython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37534440/passing-command-line-arguments-to-argv-in-jupyter-ipython-notebook), but this seems overly cumbersome. Is there a more simple and straight-forward way of doing this?

Answer (score 8):

Parameters (variables of notebook being called) can simply be initialised in cell before `%run` is called. In calling notebook:

```
for i in range (1,3):
    for j in range (0,4):
        param1 = i
        param2 = j 
        %run ./foo.ipynb
```

In order to be able to initialise these variables in notebook being run to facilitate to be used separately (to run as whole) variables can be checked for existence before initialisation [How do I check if a variable exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843277/how-do-i-check-if-a-variable-exists). In `foo.ipynb`:

```
if not 'param1' in locals():
    param1 = 1
```

As output of several runs of whole notebook would be in one cell, autoscrolling (which is on by default) may kick in. To disable it follow [Disable iPython Notebook Autoscrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36757301/disable-ipython-notebook-autoscrolling) e.g. in menu `cell`->`all output`->`toggle autoscrolling`.