# How to run an external python script in a Jupyter notebook when passing strings as arguments?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter

I'm trying to run an external python file from a Jupyter notebook. The external python file takes a file path as an argument. I'd like to know how to pass this file path to the external .py file being run, from a string variable in the Jupyter notebook.

The following is what I've tried, and the error message which is returned:

```
path = '/Users/documents/'
%run script.py path
```

Which returns:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

However I get the expected results if I run:

```
%run script.py /Users/documents/
```

I'd like to be able to store the string as a variable for ease of use (not having to edit the file path in multiple parts of a notebook. Is there an easy solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running a Jupyter notebook from another notebook with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58880620/running-a-jupyter-notebook-from-another-notebook-with-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

You should put your variable inside `{ }`. Something like this:

```
%run script.py {path}
```

*I searched few hours until I found it [here](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/jupyter+notebook+pass+python+variable+to+shell)*