# How to plot all plots in jupyter notebook without scrolling

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

right now I have a for loop in a combination with a plot:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12))
plt.subplot(221)
plt.scatter(X_pca[:, 0], X_pca[:, 1], c=y_pred)
plt.title('Clustering n: {}'.format(clusternumber))
plt.show()
```

If i run the loop:

```
for i in [2,3,4,5,10,15,20]:
    clustering(X, i)
```

It is getting quite messy:
[image]

How can I avoid the scrollbar next to the graphs? I would prefer to see the visualization without the scrolling bar, so that I can see at least 2 or 3 at the same time.

Comment: You can find the solution at -https://stackoverflow.com/a/52803744/2569613