# Jupyter Notebook Download As LaTeX or PDF fails, but works from command line using nbconvert

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Related to this question [IPython/Jupyter Problems saving notebook as PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29156653/ipython-jupyter-problems-saving-notebook-as-pdf/29809815)

On macOS,

`jupyter nbconvert example.ipynb --to latex`

works just fine.  `pandoc` is on my path at `/usr/local/bin/pandoc`.

However, within the running notebook, "File: Download as: Latex" results in an error.

```
500 : Internal Server Error
The error was:
nbconvert failed: Pandoc wasn't found.
Please check that pandoc is installed:
http://pandoc.org/installing.html
```

Is there a path variable I should be setting somewhere?