# Is there a simple way of pdf printing all files in a GitHub repository to pdfs?

Tags: pdf, github, printing, jupyter-notebook

I am taking a Udemy course for Python which has a number of its lectures typed down on in Jupiter format and stored at GitHub. Is there an easy way to print to pdf all of the lectures as opposed to opening each one individually?

For reference, I'm including the GitHub link below.

[GitHub Lectures](https://github.com/Pierian-Data/Complete-Python-3-Bootcamp)

Answer (score 1):

If you have [installed the prerequisite tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52913424/6309), then you could:

- clone the repository
- find all ipynb files
- for each one, `jupyter nbconvert --to pdf  afile`

Consider using [GNU findutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/)

Comment: Where exactly do you execute the "jupyter nbconvert --to pdf  afile" command? and I take it that "afile" is the name of the file?
Side note, I'm rather new to this.

Comment: @Mauro Where you have found each `ipynb` file. "`afile`" represent the `ipynb` file name, for each one you find.